# FastCGI + Wordpress + NGINX Prpxy

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Hey I setup Fastcgi already on nginxproxy server the site is opening but the admin panel for WordPress is not opening /wp-admin I get error: The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.Please try again later.

Here are my conf files:

nginx.conf

```
user nginx;

worker_processes 2;
worker_rlimit_nofile 1024;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;

    use epoll;
}

http {
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    server_names_hash_max_size 4096;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 2048;

    types_hash_bucket_size 64;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    client_header_buffer_size 2k;
    client_header_timeout 180s;
    client_body_timeout 180s;
    send_timeout 180s;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      off;
    tcp_nodelay     on;
    server_tokens   off;    
    include '/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf';
}
```

custom.proxy.conf

```
    proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_502;
    proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_session;
    proxy_no_cache $cookie_session;

    ## MR - increasing upload size to 64M (declare inside 'location /' not work
    client_max_body_size 64M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    proxy_connect_timeout 180s;
    proxy_send_timeout 180s;
    proxy_read_timeout 180s;
    #proxy_buffers 32 4k;
    proxy_buffers 8 128k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;

    ### MR -- change enable = @wp when using wordpress
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location = /404.html {
        root '/usr/share/nginx/html';
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root '/usr/share/nginx/html';
    }

    ### MR -- must be using nginx-special (including ngx_purge_cache)
    location ~ /purge(/.*) {
        ### MR -- just enough remove # below for enable
        #proxy_cache_purge pcache "$scheme://$host$1$request_method";
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }
location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
}
    location / {
        limit_conn addr 25;

        ## MR - no need try_files because permalink handle by apache
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:30080/;

        proxy_redirect off;

        ## MR - change $host to $domain importance for access via ip on exclusive ip domain but add X-Host still with $host
        proxy_set_header Host $domain;
        proxy_set_header X-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;


        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;

        proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;

        ### MR -- just enough remove # below for enable cache
        #proxy_cache pcache;
        proxy_cache_valid 10m;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;

        proxy_cache_key "$scheme://$host$request_uri";

        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header
                              http_500 http_502 http_504 http_404;

        open_file_cache max=1024 inactive=600s;
        open_file_cache_valid 2000s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
        open_file_cache_errors on;
    }

    ### MR -- Enable this if not using nginx cache and not for wordpress
#    location ~* ^.+\.(jpe?g|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|swf|avi|mp3)$ {
 access_log        off;
    log_not_found     off;
    expires           360d;
#        root $rootdir;
#    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    if (-d $request_filename) {
        break;
    }
```

Fastcgi.conf

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Any advice?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;` after part about error_page before `location /purge/`.